# Type mismatch when using generics on a when

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm trying to use generics in a `when`, but I get a compiling error if I try to copy the received parameter. The code below exemplifies the problem.

```kotlin
 abstract class A { abstract val prop: String};
 data class B(override val prop: String) : A();
 
 fun <T : A> execute(t: T): T {
     return when (t) {
         is B -> {
             t.copy() // doesn't compile
             // t.copy() as T // compiles
         }
         else -> t
     }
 }
```

The compiling error I get if I try without the casting is:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is Line_19.B but T was expected
```

Why the compiler can't tell that the types are consistent? Is there a way to avoid the casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason why the compiler isn't smart enough is because it treats data classes as any other class. In particularly, it treats data classes as if they can have subclasses. Consider this example instead:

```
open class B(override val prop: String) : A() {
    fun copy() = B(prop)
}
data class C(override val prop: String) : B(prop)
```

using your same `execute` will throw an exception now on `C` instances, because you can't cast to `T` since `T` is `C` but `copy()` returns a `B`

Comment: It makes sense, though I would expect that if a function returns the same type as the instance (which is the case for the `copy` of a data class) the compiler would know that types are consistent. 
Furthermore, if the `B` branch of the `when` is:
`is B -> { val typed:B = t; typed; }`
also fails at compile time, which is even more surprising.

Comment: @Markinho that's not surprising to me. It's the same situation. Just because it is matched on `is B` doesn't mean that `T` is `B`. `T` could be a subtype of `B`